# Connect to PHPMyAdmin from guest (Windows)

Tags: virtualbox

Currently I'm using Freya (host) and I've installed the PHPMyAdmin. 
I have a Windows 7 that installed in Virtualbox and I want to connect from Windows 7 (the guest) to PHPMyAdmin that installed in Freya (the host). 
Any clue? Thanks before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable ONE network adapter. Set it to NAT and start your machine. Don't need to configure anything.

On guest machine's browser type http://10.0.2.2 which will show you the same content as "localhost" in the host OS.

10.0.2.2 is the "default gateway" for NAT connections and your guest OS' IP is 10.0.2.15

Of course you can set a "HOST-ONLY" or an "Internal Network" which will allow you another advanced configurations. (The original author at superuser.com recommends to stay with NAT)

(source : https://superuser.com/questions/144453/virtualbox-guest-os-accessing-local-server-on-host-os)